# Wing IDE The debug server encountered an error in probing locals

Tags: python, debugging, wing-ide

I am running Wing IDE 5 with Python 2.4. Everything was fine until I tried to debug and set a breakpoint. Arriving at the breakpoint I get an error message: 
"The debug server encountered an error in probing locals or globals..."

And the Stack Data display looks like:
    locals  
    globals

I am not, to my knowledge, using a server client relationship or anything special, I am simply debugging a single threaded program running directly under the IDE. Anybody seen this or know how to fix it?

Wing IDE 5.0.9-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty old version of Wing and likely a bug that's been fixed since then, so trying a newer version of Wing may solve it.

However, if you are stuck with Python 2.4 then that's the latest that supports it (except that unofficially Wing 6 may work with Python 2.4 on Windows).

A work-around would be to inspect data from the Debug Probe and/or Watch tools (both available in the Tools menu).

Also, Clear Stored Value Errors in the Debug menu may allow Wing to load the data in a later run if the problem doesn't reoccur.